# Geometry behind the definition of Central simple algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional central simple algebra(CSA) over $k$. I want to view the definition of CSA geometrically.

So If I treat $A$ just as a algebra it means that $A$ is a $k-$ vector space with with distinguished element $1 \in A$ and there is multiplication map $A \otimes_{k} A \rightarrow k$. Suppose if we fix basis say $\lbrace u_{i} \rbrace$, then $u_{i}u_{j} = \sum c_{ijk} u_{k}$,  where $c_{ijk} \in k$. If we assume $A$ is associative then it just says that there are relations $\mathcal{R}$ between $c_{ijk}$, so geometrically it gives a closed subscheme $Spec(k[c_{ijk}]/\mathcal{R})$ inside $Spec(k[c_{ijk}])$. What is the geometric interpretation of "simple algebra" condition and "central algebra" condition on that subscheme. Can someone help me in understanding this definition geometrically?

Comment: Didn't you mean "a relation $\mathcal{R}$ between $u_i$" ?

Comment: They are among $c_{ijk}$, because my variables in polynomial ring are $c_{ijk}$

Comment: The $c_{ijk}$ belong to $k$, how can they be variables?

Comment: But when I am considering polynomial ring, I am consindering them as arbitrary variables.

Comment: But the $u_i$s don't belong to $k$. How are you to write your ideal $\mathcal{R}\leqslant k[c_{ijk}]$?

Comment: Associativity of $u_{i}, u_{j}$ and $u_{k}$ gives the conditions on $c_{ijk}$ that gives  relations.

Comment: May be you can explain issue a little bit so that i can understand.

Comment: Uh, can you edit your question as to explicitely describe these conditions on $c_{ijk}$? I don't get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98239/discussion-between-olivier-roche-and-sunny).

Comment: I mean probably the clearest geometric definition is that a central simple algebra is something that etale locally on the base becomes a matrix algebra. This seems different than what you're after though?